# Remove annotations containing a title equal/not equal to a String?

Tags: swift, search, filter, annotations, title

I have looked for a couple of days on trying to remove annotations that a title equal or not equal to a string that is selected from a uicollection View cell didSelect from another view controller. I get the string passed to my view controller that contains my mapview. I use a custom annotation that is the model for how the annotations are displayed.

How do I select and remove the custom annotations by their title. I already have an array of dictionaries that contains the data the annotations will use once the other annotations are removed. I know how to remove ALL the annotations, but not how to just remove the ones that have titles that are equal/not equal to the search string.

Why is nothing on the web or current for swift 3 for such a function?

I have come up with this, but only removed annotations and does display the "filteredAnnotations"

```
 var filteredAnnotations = self.mapview.annotations.filter {($0.title != nil) && isEqual(searchString) }

 print(filteredAnnotations)

 self.mapview.removeAnnotations(self.mapview.annotations)
 self.mapview.addAnnotations(filteredAnnotations)
```

using the print statement only returns an empty array of "[]"

Comment: let filteredAnnotations = mapview.annotations.filter { annotation in
                if let title = annotation.title, title != searchString {
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
            mapview.removeAnnotations(filteredAnnotations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` to get a list of all annotations that should be removed (i.e. whose title is not your search string, but isn't a `MKUserLocation`, either) and then remove them.

In Swift 3:

```
let filteredAnnotations = mapView.annotations.filter { annotation in
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return false }          // don't remove MKUserLocation
    guard let title = annotation.title else { return false }  // don't remove annotations without any title
    return title != searchString                              // remove those whose title does not match search string
}

mapView.removeAnnotations(filteredAnnotations)
```

Obviously, change that `!=` to `==` as suits your requirements, or whatever, but this illustrates the basic idea of using `filter` to identify a set of annotations whose title matches some particular criteria.

For Swift 2, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40594586/3).

Comment: Oh man, thanks Rob. That worked perfectly. I am still getting used to that filter function. Some times code hints / code completion only creates more mysteries.

Comment: OK, if you want to delete those where the title doesn't match, then of course use `!=`. But remember, you only want to remove your own annotations (i.e. if you remove `MKUserLocation`, you can get weird side effects), so exclude `MKUserLocation` from your filtered results, too.

Comment: It worked fine without the MKUSerLocation statement. As i have a custom annotation for MKUserLocation Pin/Annotation. If you go to another viewController that is not the "filterVC" it returns all the annotations as I expect it too. How would I clear the filter and return all annotations? Thanks again btw

Comment: You should only be removing annotations that you explicitly added, and so removing `MKUserLocation` is still a mistake, IMHO, but do whatever you want. But clearly, if you're not using `MKUserLocation`, you don't have to worry about it. It's just that most people overlook it (especially since the side effects are so subtle).

Comment: If you want to add back the filtered annotations, just save that array in some property, and do `addAnnotations` later.

Comment: I think you can just `return annotation.title == searchString`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov - First, he wants to remove the ones that don't match. Second, no, you can't do a simple `==` or `!=` without optional binding.

Comment: Yes you can, actually. You can compare `String?` and `String` directly

Comment: And oops, that should be a `!=`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov - But it's not a simple optional within that context. It is a `String??`. Try it. You get a "binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String??' and 'String'" error.

Comment: Oh i see, i thought it was a single optional