# Remove annotations containing a title equal to a tableView textLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, annotations

**UPDATE**

I'm still brand new to Swift so please bear with me. I have two ViewControllers. One contains a mapView and when I add an annotation, the annotation.title / annotation.subtitle is automatically added to a list on the 2nd VC. After several days of research I have this so far:

I've created a global array to store the list items as well as a global Dictionary to store the annotations and a var to represent the ViewController that the mapView is represented on

```
var annotationList = [String]()                                     
var listDetail = [String]()
var annotationDict = [String: MKAnnotation]()
var mapViewController = MapViewController?
```

When I create the annotation in the MapViewController, it's automatically added to their respective arrays and dictionaries.

```
// drop a map pin
extension MapViewController: HandleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){

    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark

    // add pin and add it to the list
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if  let streetNumber = placemark.subThoroughfare,
        let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "\(streetNumber) \(city) \(state)"
    }

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    annotationList.append(annotation.title!)
    listDetail.append(annotation.subtitle!)
    annotationDict.updateValue(annotation, forKey: annotation.title!) 
    print(annotationDict)
    }
}
```

Now in my ListViewController, I've enabled a delete option (and this is where I'm stuck). I want to be able to delete the item from the list as well as the corresponding annotation. I've updated the code to what was suggested:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

    // Get the title of the item at the selected row, and remove it from the array
        let titleToRemove = annotationList.remove(at:indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    // Use the title to find the annotation to remove
        if let annotation = annotationDict[titleToRemove] {
        print (annotation)
        mapViewController?.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation) 
        }
    } 
}
```

I printed both the annotationDict and the annotation variable, both the MKAnnotation values match, however, the removeAnnotation does not seem to run and the item is deleted from the list, but the corresponding pin remains on the map.

What might be the issue here and how can I solve it? Lmk if anything is confusing

**UPDATE:**

Both VC's are instantiated (using Storyboard ID) via a custom TabVC with the MapVC as the selected index 0 and thereby is put on the screen first. The user can freely switch between the two VC's using the tab bar. The tab bar has 2 buttons (one for MapVC and one for ListVC), both of which are connected to an `IBAction` with the following code:

```
// get access to the previous and current tab button
let previousIndex = selectedIndex
selectedIndex = sender.tag

// remove the previous ViewController and Set Button State
buttons[previousIndex].isSelected = false
let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]
previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()

// add the new ViewController and Set Button State
sender.isSelected = true
let vc = viewControllers[selectedIndex]
addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = contentView.bounds
contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

I'm not sure if its relevant, but both MapVC and ListVC are also imbedded into a NavBarController

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do for " if let title = annotationDict.keys " and why are you returning boolean

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either, but I am basing it off of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593539/remove-annotations-containing-a-title-equal-not-equal-to-a-string)

Comment: oh okay I see , I will post the way I would do it in the answer sections and try that

Answer (score 0):

Errors are pretty much self explanatory. 
For first error it says the if statement needs to have a boolean condition.
For the second error you have to use the Value of the dictionary instead of the dictionary itself. so you can do

```
MapViewController().mapView.removeAnnotations(filteredAnnotations.value)
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        annotationList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()

        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        var text = cell?.textLabel

        if let value = annotationDict[key] {

            MapViewController().mapView.removeAnnotations(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Try using this method!

Comment: It's giving me an error for "Use of unresolved identifier 'keys'" and Value of type (key:String, value: MKAnnotation) has no member value

Comment: Where did you put "keys"??

Comment: I put the "keys" as you suggested. Hmm this method gives me the same error saying that the "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type"

Comment: I just checked the method I posted and it works on my Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like you have a dictionary that saves your annotations, with the title as a key. That's ok, as long as you are **certain** that your titles will always be unique.

Rewrite your delete function like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, 
  forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        //Get the title of the item at the selected row, and remove it
        //from the array
        let titleToRemove = annotationList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        //Tell the table view to reload (There are better ways to do this.)
        tableView.reloadData()

        //Use the title to find the annotation to remove
        if let annotation = annotationDict.removeValue(forKey: titleToRemove) {
            myMapViewController.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your original code had `MapViewController().mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)`. That was wrong. The construct `MapViewController()` creates a brand new, empty map view controller that is not on screen and does not contain any annotations.

Instead, you need a pointer back to your original map view controller. To help with that you will have to explain how your 2 view controllers are created.

Comment: 1) When I delete the item from the list, I am getting an error on the MapViewController().mapView.. "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
2) What is the better way to reloadData?
3) The titles may not always be unique. Would it be a better idea to switch the key as the MKAnnotation and the value as String

Comment: In regards to the last part of your answer, the MapViewController and List ViewController were created:
`class MapViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
class ListViewController: UITableViewController`

The MapViewController is connected to a UIViewController while the ListViewController is connected to a UITableViewController, both on the Storyboard. Does that explain it?

Comment: That shows how they are defined, not how you crate them.

Comment: I apologize, how can I explain how I created them?

Comment: Which view controller is put on the screen first? How does it get there? How does the user go from the first screen to the second one, and what code is executed to create the second view controller? Do you use a segue? A button `IBAction`? Do you push the second view controller onto a navigation stack, or present it modally?

Comment: Updated the question. Does that explain it?

Comment: Hey Duncan, thanks for all the help you've provided so far! I've updated the question again. Could you help me figure out what the problem is?